# How to simulate f(1^n)=1^y where y=1+2+...n in Turing Machine Simulator?

Tags: simulator, turing-machines

I can't even imagine how to create this. I can create a transition function for `
but this looks like N factorial :(

Please I'm trying to make this work somehow but I'm not even sure if it's really factorial N or something else.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit**: I was testing it for an input of 1111 (4) and output must be: 1111111111 (10). 
So I was thinking that: 1111 on 4! thats 1111 3! 111 2! 11 1! 1 that is 10x 1. So I think it could be factorial.

**Edit**: [2-tapes-turing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR7bz.png)
I tried 2 tapes turing machine and it works for 1111 but does not for other n.

**Edit**:[turing-simulator-+-transition-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwZks.png)

Comment: 1+2+...+n=n*(n+1)/2. Try using this.

Comment: What does `^` mean in this context? Power or XOR?

Comment: Try to make an image of the state diagram and attach, then it should be more clear for us, as this listing doesn't really convey what are you trying to do.

Comment: this symbol ^ means Power

Comment: I have added a picture of a simulator. It should end for input 1111 with output  1111111111 (10x times 1) but It needs one more 1 symbol. I can make it work for 111 (output 111 11 1) or 11 (output 11 1) but that would not work for 1111 (output 1111 111 11 (missing one 1 here)).

Comment: I have added a transition picture how I think it would look using 3-tapes Turing Machine.